# Truth table for $(p\land q)\rightarrow r$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I want to know if I'm on the right track with my truth table for 
(p AND q) implies r....

```
p | q | r | p AND q | (p AND q) --> r
T   T   T      T        T
T   T   F      T        F
T   F   T      F        T
T   F   F      F        F
F   T   T      F        T
F   T   F      F        F
F   F   T      F        T
F   F   F      F        F
```

I don't really understand the implication rule when used like this so if anyone can give me a further breakdown that would be great

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let us consider the $r$ and the $(p\land q)$

Just remember the rules for implication

If we have $P\to Q$ (these are just dummy variables to show you the relationship), the possible values are as follows:

[image]

The way you wrote your table is correct.

In the first row we have `r=T, p AND q = T`, and as we know $T\to T = T$, hence you get `T`.

If we consider the second row, we have `r=F, p AND q = T`. But remember we are doing $(p\land Q)\to r$, so we have $T\to F$, which is $F$ by the table, and thats how you get `F` in row 2. Just repeat this for all the rows.

Comment: Ok, So i applied that logic to my table....So the last column should be the following??

T
F
T
T
T
T
T
F

Answer (score 0):

$P \rightarrow Q$ is always True, except when $P$ is True and $Q$ is False.

So, in your case, whenever $p \land q$ is false (rows 3 through 8), $(p \land q) \rightarrow r$ is True